# htaccess - catch-all issue

Tags: .htaccess

I'm having an issue with a catch-all rule in .htaccess that is over-riding all my other rules above it.

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.*).gif$ media/gif/$1.gif [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*).jpg$ media/jpg/$1.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.php?uri=$1 [C]
```

How can I prevent the catch-all from executing if a match is found above it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a rewrite condition

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^images.*
RewriteRule ^images/(.*).gif$ media/gif/$1.gif [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*).jpg$ media/jpg/$1.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.php?uri=$1 [C]
```

i wrote it widouth verifiying

Comment: It didn't work, however you did set me on the right path. This did work: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|jpg|js|gif|png)$ RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.php?uri=$1 [L]